# Google script to make identical format changes to multiple Google Drive Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am trying to change orientation of a bunch of Google Docs (all contained in one Google Drive File) from the default (portrait) page orientation to landscape. I am using the following code, but get a error on the "getBody" line. I suspect it is because this code is not actually "seeing" a document in the process of iterating through the documents, but I do not know how to fix that error.

> Error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getBody" of null. (line 8, file "Code")
>   page orientation

```
    function loop() {
     var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('ID');
     var files=folder.getFiles();
     while(files.hasNext()){
     var file=files.next();
     var body = doc.getBody();
     setPageOrientation(file);
    }
}
function setPageOrientation(file){
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var pointsInInch = 72;
    body.setPageHeight(8.5 * pointsInInch);  //8.5 inches
    body.setPageWidth(11 * pointsInInch); // 11 inches
  }
```

By the way, I know the 2nd function (setPageOrientation) works because I have bound it to an individual Google doc and it works.

Comment: `doc` is never defined in your first function. Hence, the error.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help. I'm a newbie, so would you mind helping me with the script. I have tried defining it, but to no avail.

Comment: You need to step back and thoroughly review your functions' logic. Note that in your second function, you never use the input argument, so only the bound Google Doc is modified. You need to review available Apps Script class methods.

Comment: I know it does not work, I suspect it does not work because it is not accessing all of the files (or any of the files in the folder), and you add the bound issue, which is in essence noting the same thing (in effect,I have already "thoroughly reviewed"), but I am so new to scripting, that I can't make sense of it. If you could be so kind to help me with the code, then it would be a big learning curve assist for me.

Comment: Your function `setPageOrientation` literally never uses its input argument `file`. No matter what you give to this function - be it the number 0, the string "Mary had a little lamb", a `Range` class object, an arbitrary Google Drive `File` instance, or a `Document` class instance opened from the file ID of a Google Drive file that corresponds to a Google Doc - the function asks Google to create a variable reference named `doc` to whatever Google Doc file the script is bound to.

Comment: Struggling to understand what you are saying, because I just don't speak this language. I thought that by following setPageOrientation function with "(file)", I was passing to the 2nd function, each successive file looped through in the first (loop) function. But, obviously, that is not the case. So, how do I do it? Also, while I used this approach bound to a Doc, before trying it here, it was not this exact script. I am not aware that a script can be bound to a Google Drive, so I don't really understand what you are saying at the end of your last comment.

Comment: Also, FWIW, the loop function, I copied from a script I found on the net that allows one to create a log file of all of the files (by name) in a folder in one's Google Drive. My interpretation of what the script was doing was in effect, finding the first file, then looping to the 2nd, and so on and writing each name to the log file (note; I left the log part of the script out as it was/is not applicable to what I am trying to do here.) So, I thought that what I was trying to do here was use that loop to successively change the page orientation on each file in a folder.

Comment: My comment was not directed at the definition of `function loop()`, it was directed the definition of `function setPageOrientation(file)`. Within the scope of its definition (search "JavaScript function scope"), you never use the function argument that you declared as `file`. Within `loop` you do call `setPageOrientation` with a parameter consisting of a `File` class instance of unknown mimetype. But, `setPageOrientation does not ever use its input argument - it only modifies the document to which the script project is bound (read about "Apps Script bound vs standalone")

Comment: Do you know how to fix this script so it works? Because, nothing you are telling me (as much as I appreciate the fact that you are commenting at all) is helping me solve my problem. I just don't have the level of knowledge to convert your advice or comments into a solution.

Comment: My very first comment addresses the source of the error. You are expected to independently research topics that you need to solve your issue, especially when given phrases to search and learn about. Please edit your question to reflect how you have attempted to remedy this original error, and the results of each attempt.

Comment: I am getting the following warning: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?
×
Bee Tee has only 1 reputation, not yet enough to chat." So, since I can't go to chat, I guess this discussion is over. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script below works. It opens up a series of documents (one by one) in my Google Drive and loops through each one, changing the format from portrait to landscape.

```
function loop() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderId');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    var id = file.getId();// To get FileId of the file
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);// To open file object as doc
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var pointsInInch = 72;
    body.setPageHeight(8.5 * pointsInInch);  //8.5 inches
    body.setPageWidth(11 * pointsInInch); // 11 inches
  }
}
```

Comment: tehhowch: I see you made some edits (added spaces, deleted spaces, etc.). For future reference, so I know whether to pay attention to this stuff when I am trying to script, since the script ran and worked, are these kind of edits critical, or is it just good form that I should aspire to?

Comment: It's critical in other languages (like python).  Although it's not critical in js, It makes the code easy to read and understand.